# Ruby array to string conversion

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a bunch of URL links in an array, for example,

```
urls = [["www.google.com"], ["www.yahoo.com"]]
#I want the urls variable to be like this below
urls = ["google.com", "www.yahoo.com"]
#I want to break up the sub-arrays in urls.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) like so

```
> urls = [["www.google.com"], ["www.yahoo.com"]]
#=> [["www.google.com"], ["www.yahoo.com"]]
> urls.flatten
#=> ["www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try somethings like

```
all_urls = Array.new
urls.each do |url| 
    all_urls.concat(url)
end
```

this should iterate through the outer array and then concatenate the inner array

Comment: use flatten instead

Comment: Even if you do not want to use `flatten` for some reason, consider using `reducers` rather than `iterators` with dummy variable. Otherwise the code looks way too phpish: `urls.each_with_object([]) { |url, memo| memo << url }`.